EBean in Play! Framework and many-to-many relationship on one class
I have a class StreamingProvider which can have child StreamingProviders. There are various combinations possible, so it is a n-n relationship:
@Entity
public class StreamingProvider extends StreamingParameterModel {

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "streaming_provider_child_parent",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="child_id"))
    private List<StreamingProvider> parentProviders;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parentProviders", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<StreamingProvider> childProviders;

}

This worked well for a long time, but I am in the process of updating Play! Framework from 2.8 to version 3.0. This means that EBeans is updated to 5.0.2 to 8.0.0.
Now I am getting the following error, and I cannot figure out what to do:
2) [Guice/ErrorInjectingConstructor]: RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.StreamingProvider
  at EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:42)
  at EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:35)
  while locating EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:20):
Binding(class DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly)
      \_ installed by: Modules$OverrideModule -> GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4
  while locating DynamicEvolutions
[...]
Caused by: IllegalStateException: @ManyToMany mapping for models.StreamingProvider.childProviders requires explicit @JoinTable with joinColumns & inverseJoinColumns. Refer issue #2157
    at AnnotationAssocManys.checkSelfManyToMany(AnnotationAssocManys.java:170)
    at AnnotationAssocManys.read(AnnotationAssocManys.java:142)
    at AnnotationAssocManys.parse(AnnotationAssocManys.java:57)
    at ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:48)
    ... 61 more

When I change it to:
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "streaming_provider_child_parent",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="child_id"))
private List<StreamingProvider> parentProviders;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "streaming_provider_child_parent",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="parent_id"))
private List<StreamingProvider> childProviders;

This results in:
2) [Guice/ErrorInCustomProvider]: IllegalStateException: Property models.StreamingProvider.childProviders has duplicate ManyToMany intersection table streaming_provider_child_parent. Please use @JoinTable to define unique table to use
  while locating ApplicationEvolutionsProvider
  at EvolutionsModule.<init>(EvolutionsModule.scala:23):
Binding(class ApplicationEvolutions to ProviderConstructionTarget(class ApplicationEvolutionsProvider) eagerly)
      \_ installed by: Modules$OverrideModule -> GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4
  while locating ApplicationEvolutions

There might be a better way of doing it, but ideally I don't want to make a chance to allow a straight forward update of the current live systems.
